# Removing Drag and Drop formatting of drop area in Python/GTK3

Tags: python, css, widget, gtk, gtk3

When implementing drag and drop in Python and GTK3 the default behaviour is that if I drag something towards the drop area, then the drop area obtains a rectangular black frame. How to remove this effect?

As per [gtk3 docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#GTK-STYLE-CLASS-DND), there is a style class `GTK-STYLE-CLASS-DND 'dnd'`, so I would think that adding

```
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider() 
css="""
.dnd {
      border-width: 0px; 
}""" 
style_provider.load_from_data(bytes(css.encode()))

Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
    Gdk.Screen.get_default(), 
    style_provider,     
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION )
```

or similar to the program should do the trick. But I had no luck with it. I kept changing other properties within the .dnd block to see if it has any effect at all but it doesn't (otherwise CSS works fine, e.g. if I change .dnd to :hover then the effect is as expected).

Comment: did you tried put only `border-width: 0px;`? Not sure if will work, but i think at this point could worth a try.

Comment: I've just tried css = """* {    border-width: 0px;}""" (with "border-width:0px;" just on its own python complains) but this also doesn't remove the black frame around drop area

Comment: i mean only the **border-width** like `css="""border-width: 0px;""" `

Comment: By saying "python complains" I mean that css="""border-width: 0px;"""  generates "GLib.Error: gtk-css-provider-error-quark: <data>:1:13Missing name of pseudo-class (1)
"

Comment: Yes, GTK+ CSS must be a valid sheet, not just a fragment. Use the GTK+ Inspector to see what the selector for your widget is; maybe something doesn't match.